# Android swipe views with independent actionbar on each view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement swipe views with viewpager, on the samples I saw the container view has an actionbar , the problem here is that each of the classes I want to use as fragment and want to swipe between them has their own actionbar.
 I couldn't find a way to implement actionbar on each fragment independently , I'll appreciate if you can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change title, MenuItems or icon, but You can't change actionbar.

This way:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments has `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method that can be overriden. Implement a custom action bar menu on this method.
Here's a sample:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Where the R.menu.menu is a xml file containing a custom menu for that fragment.
Also dont forget to add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` just incase the menu wont show up.

EDIT:
this is a sample of the xml file used for menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search" android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_filter" android:title="Filter"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_filter"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```